# Explore custom posts (CPT UI & ACF) database from WP UI

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

How can I explore the custom posts I defined with CPT Ui and ACF?

I created a custom post called "book" to actually store books and I would like to explore the database to see the number of books, see details of each books etc. but directly from the Wordpress UI or MySQL for instance.

Comment: Unless while registering you specified the post type as not public, or should not display a UI, then you should just be able to go to “Book” in the admin menu. If you meant something else you will need to elaborate.

Comment: you are right but I cannot see internal field like the UID of the post. I want for instance to use the post ID in the permalink to be able to use it in the php of the page.